# open3d constructed mesh is black

Tags: point-clouds, open3d

I'm trying to create a mesh for a simple environment (i.e. playpen, ROS noetic and Gazebo). I used 10 pcd files (recorded using HDL-32E lidar) to create the mesh environment by using the following steps:

1- Remove radius outliers (nb_points=10, radius=0.8) from pcd files and save as ply files

2- Register ply files using point-to-plane ICP and pose graph optimization

3- Combine the ply files. Apparently, the combined cloud looks good (see combined_plys.png).

4- Reconstruct the mesh environment using poisson reconstruction (depth=14). The resultant mesh file shows a black rectangle only (see front.png). The flipped side show a kind of playpen environment but in bad look (see flipped.png). It is observed that the construction process generate a warning "Extract bad average roots: 21".

I did some R&D and observed that normals play a critical role in mesh reconstruction. I created the normals using cloudcompare and then set their orientation using orient_normals_to_align_with_direction. The registered and combined cloud now have normals, apparently aligned (see pic normals_front and normals_back). Consequently, there is some improvement in the flipped mesh but still the front side is a black rectangle. Any help/hint is much appreciated.

[Combined_cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdjXn.png)

[front_mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOVAp.png)

[flipped_mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhIFM.png)

[normals_front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk0J7.png)

[normals_back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEIa1.png)

[flipped_mesh_with_normals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg31D.png)

Could you guys suggest how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I saw your question has been answered in other forum. That solution is a bit complicated and I didn't go through it. Just sharing how I solved this with a little Open3D settings.

I also encounter black reconstruction problem.
[image]

From my trials I found that it is the normals of the vertex of the mesh that we have to calculate, not those of the original point cloud. Here's what I do.

```
# Calculate the normals of the vertex
mesh.compute_vertex_normals()
# Paint it gray. Not necessary but the reflection of lighting is hardly perceivable with black surfaces.
mesh.paint_uniform_color(np.array([[0.5],[0.5],[0.5]]))
```

[image]